# MVC4 bundling/minification with IE conditional comments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, conditional-comments, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to use MVC4's new "bundling and minification".

For IE conditional comments, I'm still doing it the old way: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><link href=.../><![endif]-->` or `<!--[if lt IE 9]>@Styles.Render("~/foo")<![endif]-->` but I don't seem to get the automatic debug/release handling.

Is there a built-in way to do this? How are others doing this?

EDIT:
Also it would be great to be able to include `<noscript>` tags inside the rendered output (used for fallbacks).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Until I find a better way, I made an adaptor class called `Bundles`, which has the method:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderStylesIe(string ie, params string[] paths) {
  var tag = string.Format("<!--[if {0}]>{1}<![endif]-->", ie, Styles.Render(paths));
  return new MvcHtmlString(tag);
}
```

There is a similar method for scripts. A view calls them as such:

```
@Bundles.RenderStylesIe("lt IE 9", "~/Content/foo")
@Bundles.RenderScriptsIe("lte IE 7", "~/Scripts/bar")
```

If there is a better way, I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: Drawback to this approach, is if I have a bunch of styles or scripts that need "if lt IE 9" and "if lte IE 7" then these must be put into separate bundles, and rendered separately.

Comment: Also unsure of an elegant way to bake in the `<noscript>` tag, typically used for css fallbacks.

Comment: I found this solution quite elegant

Answer (score 5):

The soon to be released 1.1-alpha1 update will have a support doing your own tag formatting with the Scripts/Styles helpers.

There's a new DefaultTagFormat property which is by default set to:

`"<script src="{0}"></script>"`

There's also a RenderFormat method which takes in the tag format as well.  You should be able to control the rendering a bit more with these.  Is what you are trying to do possible with in a format string?

Comment: Not sure without seeing a sample/signature, but unsure if it could work with your new changes though, as the conditional comments are placed outside the script/style tag. The way I described in my answer is not ideal, but it works nicely.

Comment: Also, and this is personal preference only!, I like the ability using my class to call `Bundles` rather than `Styles` and `Scripts`. It's more self contained. The new methods you've described sound very useful though.

Comment: Basically the format would be what we use to generate individual script/link tags.  So you could do something like: Scripts.RenderFormat("<!--[if lte IE 7]>{0}<![endif]-->", paths)

Comment: Brilliant, that's what we need. Looking forward to the release.

Comment: 1.1-alpha1 is now up on nuget, so you can try this out.  http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Answer (score -2):

An alternative I found was here: https://coderwall.com/p/5zqvkg

It is a matter of preference

(Still love code above - it is much cleaner and reads easier

```
@Bundles.RenderStylesIe("lt IE 9", "~/Content/foo")
@Bundles.RenderScriptsIe("lte IE 7", "~/Scripts/bar")
```

)

Comment: The above link post a solution that does not work in practice