# Using java script code in MVC5 - where to put it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im having MVC5 application and in the view index.cshtml I need to use 
some java script code ,currently I put the script code inside the view and its working fine.
My question is where should I put this code (from best practice) and how should 
I refer to it from the view?please provide an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The approach I've written down below is my way of extracting JavaScript completely from your views.

- better to maintain (js issues -> look in js files and not in views)
- modular approach
- clear separation
- better to understand by design

In HTML5, use the `data` attribute to pass along variables from the `Model`.
This helps tremendously in porting variables from MVC (your viewmodel) to javascript.
This also allows you to keep javaScript stored in separate files as you probably would like in an MVC environment.

**1.1 Binding c# to HTML**

```
<div class="news" data-js-params="websiteName=@LocationWebsiteHelper.CurrentLocationWebsiteName()&amp;languageName=@languageName&amp;page=0&amp;itemsPerPage=@Model.MaxNumberOfItems">
```

**1.2 JS Helper functions to convert data into object literals**

Although built on jQuery, I've written 2 small functions which can help porting querystring variables into object literals and back. I use these throughout my js files:

```
// @param (qs): a query string of key value pairs (without ?)
// @param (keyDelimiter): string : character between values and keys
// @param (valDelimiter): string : character between keys and values
// @return (obj): an object literal
// @example: key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3
convertQsToLiteral: function (qs, keyDelimiter, valDelimiter) {
    var arrParams, obj = {};

    if (qs && qs.length) {
        keyDelimiter = keyDelimiter || '&';
        valDelimiter = valDelimiter || '=';
        arrParams = qs.split(keyDelimiter);

        $.each(arrParams, function (i, pair) {
            var arrPair = pair.split(valDelimiter),
                key = arrPair[0],
                val = arrPair[1];
             obj[key] = val;
        });
    }
    return obj;
},

// @param (literal): an object literal key value paired of one level deep
// @param (keyDelimiter): string  character between values and keys
// @param (valDelimiter): string : character between keys and values
// @return (string): array string representation
// @example: { key1: val1, key2: val2, key3: val3 }
convertLiteralToQs: function (literal, keyDelimiter, valDelimiter) {
    var arrQs = [],
        arrPairs, key;

    keyDelimiter = keyDelimiter || '&';
    valDelimiter = valDelimiter || '=';

    for (key in literal) {
        if (literal.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arrPairs = [];
            arrPairs.push(key, literal[key]);
            arrQs.push(arrPairs.join(valDelimiter));
        }
    }

    return arrQs.join(keyDelimiter);
},
```

**1.3 Convert HTML data into js object literals**

With these functions in mind you can pass any query string like variables into an object literal.

```
var dataParams = convertQsToLiteral($('.news').data('js-params')); // get data attr
var urlParams = convertQsToLiteral(window.location.search.substr(1)); // get url query string
```

**1.4 Example: JS modular setup to extend and override object literals**

Combined with jQuery's `$.extend()` function you can now override javascript objects in a modular approach (considering all closures a js file/module looks like this):

```
window.ProjectName = (function($, projectname){
    // default object literal
    var cfg = {
        // your default options
        idea: 'great'
    };

    // @param (options): something like the cfg object
    projectname.Module = function (options) {

        this.settings = $.extend(true, {}, cfg, options); // deep copy
        this.init();

    };

    projectname.Module.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            this.idea = this.settings.idea;
            console.log(this.idea);
        }
    };

    return projectname;
}(window.jQuery, window.ProjectName));
```

**1.5 Initializing a js module**

```
var module = new ProjectName.Module({ idea: 'even better' });
```

**2.1 Adding scripts/css to your views**

You have a couple options for attaching scripts to your views/pages/blocks:

- section defined in the baselayout (only for partial views, directly included into the baselayout)
- c# `ClientResources` (not the best approach in MVC but still doable, allows you to include external files into a partial view -> view in view)
- bundles (good or minification and modular approach)

**2.2.1 baselayout setup for sections**

```
@RenderSection("AdditionalJS", false)
```

**2.2.2 usage partial view**

```
@section AdditionalJS
{
    <script>
        var module = new ProjectName.Module({ idea: @Model.idea });
    </script>
}
```

**2.3.1 baselayout setup for view in view**

```
@Html.Raw(Html.RequiredClientResources(RenderingTags.Header))
```

**2.3.2 usage view in view**

```
ClientResources.RequireScript("/Design/js/projectname.module.js").AtHeader();
```

**2.4.1 BundleConfig setup for scripts**

```
/// <summary>
/// Register the Javascript bundles
/// Separated in libJs, projectJs and polyfillJs
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bundles"></param>
private static void RegisterScripts(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    // usage for libraries
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(
            "~/bundles/libJs").Include(
            "~/Design/js/lib/*.js"
    ));

    // project object
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(
            "~/bundles/projectJs").Include(
            "~/Design/js/project.dev.js",
            "~/Design/js/classes/*.js",
            "~/Design/js/components/*.js"
    ));

    // usage for browser support
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(
            "~/bundles/polyfillJs").Include(
            "~/Design/js/polyfills/*.js"
    ));
}

/// <summary>
/// Render scripts inside conditional comments
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865939/mvc4-bundling-minification-with-ie-conditional-comments
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ie"></param>
/// <param name="paths"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IHtmlString RenderConditionalScripts(string ie, params string[] paths)
{
    var tag = string.Format("<!--[if {0}]>{1}<![endif]-->", ie, Scripts.Render(paths));
    return new MvcHtmlString(tag);
}
```

**2.4.2 baselayout setup**

```
...
<head>
    ...
    @BundleConfig.RenderConditionalScripts("lte IE 9", "~/bundles/polyfillJs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/libJs")
<head>
<body>
    ...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/projectJs")        
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim voted Up ,you write several approach,I use the 2.2.1 with 2.2.2 ,any idea why its not working ,i.e. the script code was not invoked ...

Comment: I assume you're not in the partial view and have done a trick to include a view into another partial view. MVC doesn't allow you to use `section` for that. The "hack", if you can call it that, is to use `ClientResource`.

Comment: Added the third option for the bundlesetup. That's a lot of stuff/research in one answer so I hope it helps you and others ^^

Answer (score 7):

You better use Razor `@section` for this.

In your Layout:

```
<html>
     <head>
          <title>My Title</title>
          .....
          @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
     </head>

     <body>
          @RenderBody
     </body>
</html>
```

In your View:

```
<div id="container">
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
      ...
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // your script goes here
    </script>
}
```

Some would prefer to place `@RenderSection("Scripts")` just before the `</body>` tag instead.

Comment: From what I said the scripts remain in the view under the section scripts ,isnt it? in addition I not sure that I understand what should I do in the layout this is the code which I have there should I modify it?   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

Answer (score 2):

If you have and HTML 5 template it really doesn't matter where you place the JavaScript code, If you haver a XHTML template you should put your code inside the `<head></head>` tags.

Now with the best practices, right now the best practice is to put all your JS code just before your `</body>` closing tag. This way you make sure that your html elements tags have been parse by the browser.

When going to a production environment the best is to concatenate all your JS into a single .js file and then have it minify, that way you would have an only small js file that the client browser needs to fetch.

#### Minify your code

The term minify in frontend code (css/js) stands for a process where you trim all your spaces and line breaks, and also the function scope variables get replace with a shorter name, usually just a vowel.

```
function foo(someVar){
   return someVar;
}
```

when minified gets replaced to:

```
function foo(e){return e}
```

In `MVC4` there was the Bundling and Minification feature that could help you with this. In `MVC5` I'm not that sure.

Further Reading: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by minify,can you please provide example?

Comment: @shopiaT I just added a Minify example and a link at the bottom to the bundling and minification feature in asp.NET MVC. Please review that link to see the best practices recommended by microsoft.