# Posting javascript array of objects to MVC4 controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult BrowsePartial(IList<SearchParam> searchParams = null)
{
   //...
}
```

This is the object model:

```
public class SearchParam
{
    public string Order { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how i send data to controller:

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: { searchParams: [{ Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }, { Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }, { Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }] },
    mode: "replace",
    cache: false,
 });
```

Now, when i debug the action, i have an `IList<SearchParam>` that is correctly initialized with 3 elements. However, fields of each `SearchParam` object (`Order`, `Type` and `Value`) are initialized to null. What could be the problem here?

Comment: your data should be like: `data: { Order: "lala", Type: "lala2" }` so drop the `searchParams` and the covering array `[]`

Comment: but it has to be an array of objects. not a single object!

Comment: is there any way to acomplish that?

Comment: it's an object literal => see [my answer elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893246/using-java-script-code-in-mvc5-where-to-put-it/22893588#22893588)

Comment: The way you wanna do it, is send 3 ajax requests at once. So you have to deal with your array first, then send it 3 times.

Comment: is there no other way of sending array of objects to mvc controller?

Comment: I don't believe you can send this in a single request as your data `{ key:value }` becomes part of the url in the `GET` request => `?Order=lala&Type=lala2`. Since you use the same properties in a single request you'll have to loop through that array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the only way you can send your array parameter in a single request is to stringify it, and deserialize in your controller.

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: { searchParams: JSON.stringify([{ Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }, { Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }, { Order: "fghfdhgfdgfd", Type: "sasdsa", Value: "saddsadsads" }])},
    mode: "replace",
    cache: false,
 });


public ActionResult BrowsePartial(string searchParams = null)
{
    SearchParam params = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchParam>(searchParams);
}
```

But I maybe mistaken ;)