# Bootstrap using Modal where to place jquery and bootstrap when using bundleconfig

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I use bundle config for my jquery and bootstrap.  I have notice that I am getting different results depending on where I place the jquery and bootstrap.

**Using standard code**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "CreateWebOrder";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2>CreateWebOrder</h2>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
        @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#shipToModal">Add</button>

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I add the below scripts and link to the top of the form the modal is working correctly.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**I would like to use bundle config and add this to the _Layout page.**

**When I add my jquery and bootstrap on the _layout page at the bottom of the form and remove the scripts and link from the form**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myjquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**The modal will display for a second then clear and only show a faded background.**

My question is why can't I use my bundle config rather then placing the scripts and link at the top of the form.  What is causing this problem?

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893246/using-java-script-code-in-mvc5-where-to-put-it/22893588#22893588) can be useful to you.

Comment: "and remove the scripts **and link** from the form" ... ?

Comment: Hi Tim,  When I remove the "script src" and "link href" for jquery and bootstrap from my mvc page and the the jquery and bootstrap to the bundle config and add the bundle to the layout page I encounter the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might be if you have included the Jquery file or the bootstrap js file more than once. I would suggest you to check your bundle config to see if the Jquery js file or the bootstrap file is not getting invoked more than once.
Multiple references of bootstrap js file can instantiate the modal more than once which can toggle its visibility and add strange behavior to it.

If this does not work please try and check your console to provide some error information if it persists.

Comment: Thanks Novice.... That did the job.  I had multiple bootstraps.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have to generate 15 reputation before I can do that.